# comprobar palabras en peticiones entrantes a rutas en servidor antes de renderizar la página

Tags: apache2, servidor

Quiero comprobar una conexión entrante, por ejemplo si se quieren conectar a mi servidor apache2 desde la IP 12.1.3.3, y dentro del servidor quieren acceder a la ruta /hello. Antes de renderizar la página quiero comprobar si en la ruta hay ciertas palabras. ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?, estaba intentandolo con iptables pero no encuentro la manera.

Comment: "quiero comprobar si en la ruta hay ciertas palabras" Podrías dar un ejemplo más concreto de lo que quieres lograr?

Comment: por ejemplo si hay etiquetas como <h1> en la ruta como por ejemplo 
127.0.0.1/index.html/<h1>gola</h1>, detectarlas antes de que cargue la página

Comment: detectarlas y hacer qué?

Answer (score 0):

Si quieres denegar urls que traen caracteres `<`, `>`, puedes hacerlo en Apache2 con [modrewrite](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html). Por ejemplo:

```
RewriteRule [<>] - [F]
```

devolverá error 403 (Forbidden).

Comment: perfecto, me sirve pero y si quiero también chequear las conexiones de un nginx? me vale el mismo módulo?

Comment: No, Nginx es totalmente incompatible con Apache